# Changing the color of a dropdown in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dropdown, html-select

Unfortunately, I could not find any given solution to solve my problem.

I need to change a specific option's color in a given dropdown .

EDIT: This is the HTML:

```
<label> Select Lec:</label>
   <select id="lect">
      <option value="0"> Select</option>
   </select>
```

This is where I call the function changeColor:

```
$("#algorithmResult").append("<p class='added_value'>Recommended: " + algorithm_result[course].Lec_name + "</p>");
changeColor(algorithm_result[course].Lec_name);
```

This is the following code:

```
$("#lect").append("<option id='" + res[i].Lec_name+"'  >" + res[i].Lec_name + "</option>");
```

Now I have the following function triggered:

```
function changeColor(value) {                   
            document.getElementById(value).style.color = "green";

        }
```

Now, I have debbuged and res[i].Lec_name and value are the same string.
For some reason it doesn't work, can someone help ?

Comment: Please include your html.

Comment: Please edit the post to include all relevant code. You're never calling the `changeColor` method.

Comment: Changing the color of an `option` element will generally not work. In some browsers on some systems, it might change the color, while on others it won't.

Comment: What/How/What is calling `changeColor()`?  Is it in a function? What is `#algorithmResult`?

Comment: I have edited when i use changeColor(), the algorithmResult id is irrelevant in this case, the most important things is that i get the value i need to the changeColor function but I can't change the color although it seems to be the appropriate way.

Comment: You show `changeColor()` being called, but we have no when this script is executed.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand it right you are trying to highlight options so i have created a simple function for it where you have to give select element in first param then array of indexes to assign selected class on it then put style to that class in css

```js
function changeColor(select,indexes){
    Array.from(select.children).forEach((each,i)=>{
        if(indexes.indexOf(i) === -1){
            each.classList.remove("selected")
        }
        else {each.classList.add("selected")}
    })
}


//example use
const select = document.querySelector("select")
changeColor(select,[0,3,5,8]) // [main select element , indexes to highlight]
```

```css
.selected {
  background:blue;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<select name="" id="">
    <option value="select1">select1</option>
    <option value="select1">select1</option>
    <option value="select1">select1</option>
    <option value="select1">select1</option>
    <option value="select1">select1</option>
    <option value="select1">select1</option>
    <option value="select1">select1</option>
    <option value="select1">select1</option>
    <option value="select1">select1</option>
</select>
```